# std::variate_generator in VS2012

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012

I used `std::variate_generator` in the following way in a VS2010 project:

```
#include <random>
...
using std::variate_generator;
using std::mt19937;
using std::uniform_real_distribution;

typedef mt19937                                     Engine;
typedef uniform_real_distribution<float>            Distribution;
typedef variate_generator< Engine, Distribution >   Generator;  

Generator r( Engine((DWORD)time(NULL)), Distribution(0.0f, 1.0f) ); 

// from now, calling float rnd = r() gave me a random number between 0.0f and 1.0f in rnd.
```

I've now put this code into a VS2012 solution and the error message I'm getting is that `std::variate_generator` is not a member of `std`.

Has `std::variate_generator` moved or been removed?

Comment: aah.  It's been removed.  Sheesh.   http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n1933.pdf

Comment: Some additional comments; You don't have to specify that range for the distribution since zero to one is the default; you can use the `<chrono>` library to get a time if that's how you want to initialize the engine, and if you use one of the higher resolution clocks then you'll be able to initialize a different engine faster than once per second; You could also use `std::random_device` to get a seed; If you want an explicit cast (to silence a warning I guess?) `DWORD` probably isn't the type you should use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

variate_generators aren't used in the final standard version of `<random>`. variate_generator was part of tr1 but never made it into the standard, so I'm a bit surprised `std::variate_generator` worked in VS2010 (as opposed to `std::tr1::variate_genrator`). I believe it still exists in VS2012's tr1 namespace though.

You can do the following instead:

```
#include <random>
#include <functional> // for std::bind
...
using std::mt19937;
using std::uniform_real_distribution;

typedef mt19937                                     Engine;
typedef uniform_real_distribution<float>            Distribution;

auto r = std::bind(Distribution(0.0f, 1.0f), Engine((DWORD)time(NULL)));

// from now, calling float rnd = r() gave me a random number between 0.0f and 1.0f in rnd.
```

Comment: will this be backward compatible to VS2010?

Comment: Yes, vs2010's implementation of `std::bind` is sufficient for this to work.